# Error sending data to PHP form

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to send an email from my application with a PHP contact form, but the details can't be sent from the application for some reason. Please tell me what is the problem.. I've attached the the php form i'm using at the end.

when I try to send an email using the web-browser and writing: http://www.bergerz.co.il/wp-content/themes/ecobiz/sendemailfromapp.php/?name=MYNAME&subject=SUBJECT&email=yositsa@gmail.com&message=MESSAGE, it's working perfectly.

```
-(IBAction)send:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bergerz.co.il/wp-content/themes/ecobiz/sendemailfromapp.php"];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"REQUEST"];

    NSString * paramDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&subject=%@&email=%@&message=%@",[txtName.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtSubject.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtEmail.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtMessage.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData*paramData = [paramDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:paramData];

    NSURLResponse * response;
    NSError * error;

    NSData * aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];//excute of data to the internet 
    NSString * requestData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([requestData isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sent"]])
    {
        lblStatus.hidden = NO;
        lblStatus.text = @"Message Sent..";
    }
    else if ([requestData isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO_NAME_ERROR"]])
    {
        lblStatus.hidden = NO;
        lblStatus.text = @"Name is too short";
    }
    else if ([requestData isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO_EMAIL_ERROR"]])
    {
        lblStatus.hidden = NO;
        lblStatus.text = @"Email is too short";
    }
    else if ([requestData isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EMAIL_WRONG_ERROR"]])
    {
        lblStatus.hidden = NO;
        lblStatus.text = @"Email wrong error";
    }
    else if ([requestData isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO_MESSAGE_ERROR"]])
    {
        lblStatus.hidden = NO;
        lblStatus.text = @"Message is too short";
    }
    else if ([requestData isEqualToString:@"NULL"])
    {
        lblStatus.hidden = NO;
        lblStatus.text = @"EMPTY";
    }
    NSLog(@"request: %@",request);
    NSLog(@"requestData: %@",requestData);
    NSLog(@"aData: %@",aData);
}
```

here is the php file: http://www.pastebin.com/BvaiMs04

I've edited the message to my latest code, still he isn't working.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Where does it stop?

Comment: The only error that I get is 'FROM_IS_EMPTY'. this is the first error of the PHP form. even when the form is full i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ParamDataString should be `name=%@&subject=%@...` without the `/?`.

AND: You have to escape the input strings: `[txtName.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtSubject.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ...`

or fill everything into a NSDictionary and use `urlEncodedString`:

```
NSDictionary *postParams = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: txtName.text, @"foo", txtSubject.text, @"bar", nil];
//...
NSString *sPostParams = [postParams urlEncodedString];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[sPostParams UTF8String] length:[sPostParams length]]];
```

Found another bug: HTTP method should be POST, "_REQUEST" does not exist... `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];`

Comment: it wont work with the same error that I wrote up, 'FROM_IS_EMPTY' this is the first error message of the PHP file, usually when the form has been sent empty.

Comment: Edited the answer. Try again ;)

Comment: Hey man, I did exactly as you said, still its not working.. I used the [txtName.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] method. i'm losing my mind already hahaha.. *The error is still 'NULL': requestData: NULL.

Comment: hahaha, actually i'm kinda new to Obj-c, this is my teacher's code. no wonder that you find bugs.. his very messy..

Comment: can I just use ASIHTTPRequest? I will read about it and use it, I think it will be better, no?

Comment: Thanks alot dude! it's working, the mistake was to replace POST instead of REQUEST.. I didn't saw the last line you were edited.. thanks!